# Something like Excels Macro function in Enterprise Architect

Tags: automation, enterprise-architect

I wonder if there is something like the Macro function from Excel in Enterprise Architect. For example, I have the following procedure in EAv15: add a new tagged value xy, make some changes to a DDL Template based on the value of xy (If the value is "true" then add system versioning to the the table or something like that).

So the goal is to have something to automate this procedure in the Enterprise Architect. So far I was thinking if it would be possible with something like the macro function from excel or by writing a certain script.

Thanks in advance for all comments and ideas!

Comment: You're always free to use external programming and the API to get more comfort than the internal scripting of EA offers. I for myself use Pythhon.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to tick the check mark at Geerts answer (and eventually an upvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Architect has a scripting feature that allows you to automate tasks.
You can write scripts in **VBScript**, **Jscript** or **Javascript**

See **Specialize | Tools | Scripting**

Depending on the type of group a script is in, it can be started from the context menu **Specialize | Script | [name of the script]**

Best place to start for the documentation is here: https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/automation/automation_interface.html

Comment: I wonder whether that is the _best_ place. It's the *only* place from Sparx, though. Sigh. Anyhow, it's nothing like that macro recording from Excel.

Comment: I didn't see anything about recording in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm out of the Excel business since ages. Wasn't there something like "start record", "do some click clack", "end record", "replay"? Somehow the question made me think it's in that direction. I might be on the wrong track, though.

Comment: Yes, in Excel you can record macro's. You then get horrible vba code that you can use to replay your actions. But "macro" in general are the term used in excel for anything vba, not specifically only the recorded ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! @GeertBellekens your answer was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Sorry, but i have one more question: How exactly can i edit a DDL template via a script?

Comment: Comments aren't really meant to ask questions, but I don't think you can. To be sure you can ask this as a question and maybe someone else knows.